# Can You provide a SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am looking to get all the saturdays from the beginning of the year and assign them number.

Like eg: if I gave a variable 80,4 then it should take all 80 saturdays from the begning of the year and divide by 4 and give the size numbers

```
SL       DATES      SIZE    
1       02-JAN-16   1    
2       09-JAN-16   1    
3      16-JAN-16    1    
4      23-JAN-16    1    
5      30-JAN-16    2    
6      06-FEB-16    2    
7      13-FEB-16    2    
8      20-FEB-16    2    
9      27-FEB-16    3    
10     05-MAR-16    3    
11     12-MAR-16    3    
....    …    
....    …    
....    …    
72     20-MAY-17    19    
73     27-MAY-17    19    
74     03-JUN-17    19    
75     10-JUN-17    19    
76     17-JUN-17    20    
78     24-JUN-17    20
79     01-JUL-17    20
80     08-JUL-17    20
```

Comment: SO is a place where you can post your code, explain your problem and ask for help in solving it; from your question, it seems that you need a free coding service, more than SO. Please post what you tried so far and explain the problem you encountered

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. First try it yourself, then post code, we can then tell you a solution. You will learn a lot if you do it in this manner. Thnks

Comment: Please provide a working [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) of what you have so far, and describe what your issue is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787370/rule-iterate-v-n this is what i did..

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Are you saying that this is the same question than the other one, but there you posted the only code and here the only data?

Comment: Its basically that I want.. When you compile it willl show output much similar to this one.

Comment: the thing is stackoverflow.com/questions/36787370/rule-iterate-v-n is not replied by any one. I thot it must be difficuilt to understand the code. so I have put in the above example,

Comment: OK, but this way you will confuse people. Edit the original question by adding this sample data, than this question will be unuseful and it would be better to delete it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEVEL AS SL,
       NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ) + 7 * LEVEL - 8, 'SATURDAY' ) AS DATES,
       CEIL( LEVEL / :divisor ) AS "SIZE"
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :limit;
```